# How to create unit test for cakephp 3 Flash error in controller

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp-3.0, phpunit

Below is the codecov coverage of my cakephp 3 application. How do I write a unit test that covers flash error?

[image]

Comment: For example by posting data that doesn't pass the `Employees` table's validation/application rules.

Comment: Or are you wondering how to write the assertion that the flash message was generated in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

You'd best perform an assert on the response body. After all, the Flash messages are nothing but text in a div. An example of a success Flash output:

```
<div class="message success" onclick="this.classList.add('collapse')">Entity saved</div>
```

A possible assert for any success or error message could look like:

```
$this->assertResponseContains('<div class="message success"');
$this->assertResponseContains('<div class="message error"');
```

Or you could copy the entire expected Flash output.

Answer (score 0):

As of CakePHP 3.7 you can use `assertFlashMessage` and a few other helpers, there are some [examples in the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/testing.html#testing-flash-messages)

For your case, your test code could look something like this:

```
class EmployeesControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use IntegrationTestTrait;

    public function testEmployeeAddErrorMessage()
    {
        $bad_data = ['bad' => 'data'];
        $this->post('/employees/add', $bad_data);

        $this->assertFlashMessage('The employee could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use $this->enableRetainFlashMessages(); before post method.